# Problem when displaying an object on another php page

Tags: php, oop

I have a page 'player.php' where I have the object player and the functions of this and another page 'index.php' where a small form is displayed where the player's name is added and the new player is created.

If I put all the code on the page 'player.php' it works correctly, add to the player and it shows on the list button every new player that is created.

But as I have it separate it does not work, I have added include ("player.php") but it still does not work.

**player.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

class Player {

    private $players;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
          $this->players = array();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

     public function addPlayer($onePlayer)
     {
          $this->players[] = $onePlayer;

          return $this;
     }

     public function printPlayers()
     {
          foreach($this->players as $player){
               echo $player.'<br />';
          }
     }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}



function printForm()
{
     echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 73px;">
                <h2>Add Players</h2>
                <label>Add the name : </label><INPUT class="form" TYPE = "text" NAME = "name"> <br><br>
                <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "add" name="action">
                <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "list" name="action">
            </ FORM>';
}

// Load the player data of the session and if it does not exist create a new player.
function loadData()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['player']) ? $_SESSION['player'] : new Player();
}


// Save the player's data in the session.
function saveData($player)
{
   $_SESSION['player'] = $player;
}

/**** If I put the index.php code here it works fine

printForm();

$player = loadData();

if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case 'add':
            $player->addPlayer(new Player($_POST['name']));
            saveData($player);
            break;

        case 'list':
            echo '<hr />';
            $player->printPlayers();
            break;
    }
}
*****/

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

include("player.php");


printForm();

$player = loadData();

if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case 'add':
            $player->addPlayer(new Player($_POST['name']));
            saveData($player);
            break;

        case 'list':
            echo '<hr />';
            $player->printPlayers();
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a new instance of class Player, like this:

```
#new instance of Player class
$player = new Player();
#call loadData function
$player->loadData();
```